# testng executes @Test annotated methods from base class again while executing sub class

Tags: java, inheritance, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have 2 classes - Class A and Class B - class A containing 2 test methods and Class B containing 1 test method annotated with @Test and priority in TestNG

Class B extends Class A as class B need to use WebDriver object initialized in Class A (in one of the methods annotated with @Test (priority=1))

When TestNG run the tests, it runs both methods of Class A and then runs the method in Class B. And then it runs the 2 methods of Class A again and completes the test

Why does it execute methods of Class A again? How to prevent it from doing this?

Comment: It would be better if you can share the sample code here for better understanding of the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use a `@Test` to do the initialisation! Use a `@Before` method or something like that. If this is a very complex method, then I would try to make it static and reusable or extract it to an `abstract` class, which both classes (A and B) are extending from.

Comment: Hi Niklas, do you know the reason TestNG executes base class methods again while running sub class methods ?

Comment: As far as I know is TestNG creating/instanciating the class and then trying to find the with `@Test` annotated methods per reflection and then running this methods. So there's no differentiating if methods are in the class or in any classes the class extends from.